# WCF webservice: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request while sending large input

Tags: wcf, web-services, soapui

I am connecting to a WCF based webservice. For certain methods, the input contains a list of objects/structures. When the number of items in this list increases beyond a certain number, the service fails with `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` when I try to test the same using SOAPUI. I tried changing the web.config file with the following changes:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" />

   <binding name="basicHTTP" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" maxBufferSize="98547" maxBufferPoolSize="258547">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
   </binding>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was solved by the `maxReceivedMessageSize` setting. Initially in my binding, I did not set the `bindingConfiguration` explicitly, though the `basicHttpBinding` was declared and set.

As such changes in `maxReceivedMessageSize` in the binding was not getting applied and the default setting of 64kb was active. I have set the bindings like:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding"
 name="AMS" bindingName="basicHttpBinding" contract="Entity.AccuchekMobility.Service.IAccuchekMobilityService" />

   <binding name="basicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:02:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="4194304">
```

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that maxReceivedMessageSize is in Bytes whereas maxRequestLength is in KiloBytes. Also for buffered transfer set the buffer size to the same value as max message size. How large is the failing input?

Comment: The failing request is hardly few kB. It is far below 1 MB, I however shall update the exact size later.

Comment: So, may I expect some more guidance please?